# HONDA 125 CLICK Automatic Carburetor tuning?

Tags: honda, tuning

Hope someone can help me, please:  I have a Honda 'Click' 125 automatic. When hot it runs well, but when cold or warming up it will not accelerate, or sometimes will not even speed up enough to engage the clutch (even when I open the throttle ... no change in engine revs)  Sounds like Carburetor tuning. Normally I would go to mechanic but I am in poor area of Asia and three local mechanics have ripped me off and made it worse each time and just shrugged when I came back to say it's not right :(  Can I adjust it myself? Any suggestions or links to good advice - many thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome.